# exec user process caused "exec format error" during setup

Tags: haproxy-ingress

I'm trying to install haproxy-ingress under Kubernetes ver 1.18 (hosted on raspberry pi).

The master node has been correctly labeled with role=ingress-controller.

The kubectl create works also fine:

```
# kubectl create -f https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/resources/haproxy-ingress.yaml
namespace/ingress-controller created
serviceaccount/ingress-controller created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-controller created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-controller created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-controller created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-controller created
configmap/haproxy-ingress created
daemonset.apps/haproxy-ingress created
```

But then, the pod is in crash loop:

```
# kubectl get pods -n ingress-controller -o wide
NAME                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
haproxy-ingress-dpcvc   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          30s   192.168.1.101   purple.cloudlet   <none>           <none>
```

And the logs shows that error:

```
# kubectl logs  haproxy-ingress-dpcvc -n ingress-controller
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Does anyone experience something similar? Can this be related to the arm (32-bit) architecture of the raspbian that I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

raspberry pi's run arm architectures which unfortunately are not supported by haproxy-ingress.

Comment: However since this [pr](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/pull/472) one can build your own custom controller (didn't test myself)